# using horizontal .scrollTo in jQuery without causing jumps in page

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, scrollto

I'm trying to implement a tab slider using the .scrollTo plug-in for jQuery. Here's a demo of the project right now: http://www.joshualoves.com/temp/lura/

The problem is that when an anchor is clicked on, the page "jumps" down to the location of that anchor. It also switches to correct div, but without actually scrolling.

I've implememnted scrollTo before, so I'm not sure what the problem is - here is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div.slideThumbnail').click(function () {
    $('#slideshowMask').scrollTo(("#" + $target), 800);                                 
    return false;
});
});
```

$target is set when the user clicks on the link in the thumbnail that corresponds to the slide.

Comment: Do you get an error message in the console?

Comment: He gets 404 not found when he loads the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem might be that in the firebug console i have

```
 "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://www.joshualoves.com/temp/lura/jquery.scrollTo.js"
```

So it seems you are not loading the plugin